# Why can't I attach a singleton method to another object?

Tags: ruby, oop, singleton, singleton-methods

```
some_string = "i love lamp"
another_string = "i love desk"
def some_string.lovehate
    if match /love/
        sub /love/, "hate"
    elsif match /hate/
        sub /hate/, "love"
    end
end

puts some_string.lovehate # => "i hate lamp"
puts another_string.respond_to? :lovehate # => false
m = some_string.method(:lovehate).unbind
m.bind(another_string).call # fails
```

This fails with

```
singleton method called for a different object (TypeError)
```

So clearly the ruby programmers thought this was a bad idea for some reason. My question is what is stopping me from doing this?

Comment: (It might merely be an implementation detail not related to the opinions of "the ruby programmers".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is consistent with how UnboundMethods normally work. The object you bind them to has to be a kind_of? the class the method came from. `another_string` is not descended from `some_string`'s singleton class (just like no other object is), so you can't bind the the methods of `some_string`'s singleton class to it.